# Error handling: Run function if function fails

Tags: go, error-handling

When ssh with PublicIpAddress fails, run ssh with PrivateIpAddress. I'm handling this way but it doesn't seem to work, ssh with PublicIpAddress exits with code 255 and doesn't try ssh with PrivateIpAddress.

```
    for _, machine := range selected {
        err := ssh(machine.KeyName, Username, machine.PublicIpAddress)
        if err != nil {
            err = ssh(machine.KeyName, Username, machine.PrivateIpAddress)
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
```

SSH func

```
func ssh(keyname string, user string, address string) error {
  var err error
  //

  if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
  }
  return err
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your condition be `if err != nil` instead of `if err == nil` to call `ssh()` with private IP address?

Comment: @icza mistake, edited.

Comment: So what do you expect? Why do you write it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I expected that when the ssh connection with publicipaddress timeout or throws an error, it should try running the ssh connection with the privateipaddress.

Comment: Now it justs exits with 255 and doesn't try the ssh with privateipaddress

Comment: Inside `ssh()` you should return a non-`nil` error when the exit code is `255`. I assume you return `nil` but we don't see what's inside `ssh()`.

Comment: I just update the ssh  func to reflect that `if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil { fmt.Println(err.Error())} `

Comment: There's your error: you used short variable declaration which creates a new `err` variable shadowing the outer one. Use `=` instead of `:=`, like this `if err = cmd.Run(); err != nil {}`